# Prevent middle mouse click in a href with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This may sound like a dumb question but just hear me out.

I'm trying to prevent a link from being clicked with the middle-mouse button. The UX reason I'm doing this, is because the anchor loads AJAX content, and the user don't know that until he clicks it.

Here's the problem:

```
/**
*   mousedown or mouseup
*/
$(document).on("mousedown", function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is("a.load-some-ajax-stuff") && e.which === 2) {
        alert('Foo'); // only works if there's an alert
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

/**
*   click
*/
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is("a.load-some-ajax-stuff") && e.which === 2) {
        e.preventDefault(); // should work, but doesn't catch middle-mouse clicks
    }
});
```

Snippet

```js
$(document).on('mousedown', "a.load-some-ajax-stuff", function(e) { 
 if( (e.which == 2) ) {
            // alert('foo');
     e.preventDefault();
         }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="load-some-ajax-stuff">I won't open a new tab when you middle click me</a>
```

#### Edit

It seems that the Snippet above works in Safari, but not Chrome.

Comment: Sounds more like a UX problem. I'd suggest using a button instead of an anchor

Comment: @Phil Actually it's a gallery, head to this link and try to "use" the gallery to see what I mean: http://cbpw.scriptpie.com/lightbox-gallery/#

Comment: @Phil in my case it's a bit worse, because I use this gallery as a content to hold Portfolio items, so the most natural thing is to open it with middle-click

Comment: The only other advice I could give would be to have the anchor's `href` actually open something useful. This is what's called *"graceful degradation"*. Seems Chrome (and possibly others) do not allow client-side code from preventing expected behaviour.

Comment: @Phil changing the anchor's `href` to something useful does not change the outcome at all.

Comment: @clabe45 what I mean is that if OP cannot prevent middle-clicks opening tabs, then the best they can do is have that new tab show something useful

Comment: Showing more code would help to find a solution. Maybe trying to prevent the tab to open isn't the best thing to do. Read about [x/y problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)